# How to parse a nested json file if there are to many secondlevel-fields?

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to parse a json file with gson and i found multiple solutions. But my problem is, that i have to many fields? to actually write them all down in a class. How can i get the information inside cars + the color, without creating a class with name1 - name564?
Here is an example json:´

```
{"test":
    {"Name1":
        {"number":"123",
        "color":"red",
        "cars":{"BMW":1,
            "PORSCHE":2,
            "MERCEDES":4,
            "FORD":6}
        },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    "Name564":
        {"number":"143",
        "color":"blue",
        "cars":{"BMW":9,
                "PORSCHE":2,
                "MERCEDES":3,
                "FORD":7}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate name for each object?  Isn't the "number" field unique?

Comment: I did not create the json file nor the structure of it. I am just curious how to parse something like that.

Comment: That's going to be tough to work around.  I am also curious what a solution would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` for mappings. Here's code to parse your example:

```
class JsonRoot {
    Map<String, JsonName> test;
}

class JsonName {
    String number;
    String color;
    Map<String, Integer> cars;
}

...
JsonRoot jsonRoot;
Gson gson = new Gson();
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.json"))) {
    jsonRoot = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonRoot.class);
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant answer than mine :)

Comment: Tried your solution and it works flawless. Didnt even think about maps. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I get the problem exactly, but if I do, the solution could be to create a new Java class, named say `MyClass`. 
MyClass will have Name1, ..., Name564 as instances and number, color, cars as attributes, like the following:

```
class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private int number; //use int or String if you prefer
    private String color; //you can also use enum instead
    private Map<String, Integer> cars;

    public MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        cars = new HashMap<>(); // or any other map implementation, depending on the needs
    }

    public void addCar(String model, int numCars) {
        cars.put(model, numCars); // if you always want to replace, add any necessary checks before that
    }

    //or you can use setCars, seeing test.get("cars") as Map
    public void setCars(Map<String,Integer> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Then, as you iterate the json doc, you can set the field that you encounter. For every "Name" element that you meet, you can create a new instance of MyClass: `MyClass currItem = new MyClass("Name"+counter)`, where `counter` is a counter you initialize from 1 until the size of children of "test" element.

`doc.get("test").get("Name"+counter)` will give you the next item. You can use `.get("color")`, `.get("number")`, and `.get("cars")` for the corresponding fields.

I hope this helps.